# How to improve response time using guzzle promise?

Tags: php, promise, guzzle6, guzzle

I am looking for help here to understand whether my code is right approach or not. Because I can't see much improvement in response time. I used guzzle promise to reduce my overall performance.

Existing code :

```
protected function sampleFunction(&$outputArray){
        foreach($outputArray as $key => $images){
            foreach($images as $index => $image){
              $result = NewClass::ClassSampleFunction($image->path, $this->samplePoint); // This is expensive function calls in current code. 
              }
        }
    }
```

New code using guzzle promise callback :

```
protected function sampleFunction(&$outputArray){
        
        foreach($outputArray as $key => $images){
            $promises = array();
            foreach($images as $index => $image){
                $promises[$index] = $this->promiseFunction($image,$index); 
            }

            $results = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\settle($promises)->wait(); 
            foreach ($results as $resultkey => $value) { 
                    $search_point_image_xy_array = $value['value']->toArray();
                    // some logic to use result and put in another response array.
            } 
          } 
    }

protected function promiseFunction($image,$index){
      $promise =  new Promise(
                        function () use ($image,$index,&$promise) {
                            $response = NewClass::ClassSampleFunction($image->path, $this->samplePoint);
                            $promise->resolve($response);
                        },
                        function () {
                            // do something that will cancel the promise computation (e.g., close
                            // a socket, cancel a database query, etc...)
                        }
                    );
        return $promise;
    }
```

This new code trying to call `NewClass::ClassSampleFunction($image->path, $this->samplePoint);` this expensive function call using guzzle promise without external endpoint. But after this also expected some reduction in response time but not changes whereas sometime its more than old code.

Mention function call `NewClass::ClassSampleFunction($image->path, $this->samplePoint);` this run suppose I have first for loop 4 range and second has 10 per first for loop then total 40 times calls goes to this function. If I used async call then First call goes without it finish second goes and vice versa. This can help to use waiting time in old code

What I am doing wrongly ? Any help or recommendation ?

Comment: Which changes are you looking for? Downloading stuff from an external server still takes time. You could try to debug this using blackfire.io

Comment: This is local function. Nested in multiple local function there is external call. I can't change that external call. Want to use local function as promise to async call.

Comment: My expectation should if It old code is taking time to finish 5 sec. After using promise async call it should reduce to 500 or 600 ms because no calls should wait for first call to finish.

Comment: And which calls are still waiting? What have you tried to check for any difference, besides monitoring the time between request start and finish? As these "expensive calls" still have to happen anytime in your application (this means: the execution takes time, regardless of when this happens), I don't think that your are monitoring them properly

Comment: Mention function call `NewClass::ClassSampleFunction($image->path, $this->samplePoint);` this run suppose I have first for loop 4 range and second has 10 per first for loop then total 40 times calls goest to this function. If I used asyc call then First call goes without it finish second goes and vice versa. This can help to use waiting time in old code.

Comment: And what have you tried to debug why the performance is not better in the end? Why not run a profiler like blackfire.io to check for differences?

Comment: I created profile using xdebug not seeing improvement. Even in browser console not seeing response time improvement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225197/discussion-between-aviboy2006-and-nico-haase).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I able to improve performance by some level by using `eachPromise` from `guzzle/promise`.

Revise code :

```
protected function sampleFunction(&$outputArray){
        
        foreach($outputArray as $key => $images){
            $promises = array();
            foreach($images as $index => $image){
                $promises[$index] = $this->promiseFunction($image,$index); 
            }

           $eachPromise = new EachPromise($promises, [
          // how many concurrency we are use
          'concurrency' => count($promises),
          'fulfilled' => function ($response,$index) use (&$images, &$outputArray)
           {
             //logic for other operation.
               
            },
          'rejected' => function ($reason) {
          }
        ]);
          } 
    }

protected function promiseFunction($image,$index){
      $promise =  new Promise(
                        function () use ($image,$index,&$promise) {
                            $response = NewClass::ClassSampleFunction($image->path, $this->samplePoint);
                            $promise->resolve($response);
                        },
                        function () {
                            // do something that will cancel the promise computation (e.g., close
                            // a socket, cancel a database query, etc...)
                        }
                    );
        return $promise;
    }
```

**Reference article** : https://medium.com/@ardanirohman/how-to-handle-async-request-concurrency-with-promise-in-guzzle-6-cac10d76220e